# Не работает 'header('Location:url")' при AJAX запросе

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Вот метод отвечающий за отправку запроса.

```
sendData:function(data , url) {
    var body = 'user='+JSON.stringify(data),
        request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        url = url;
    request.open('POST', url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4) {
            if(this.status == 200) {
                if(this.responseText != null) {
                    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =  request.responseText;
                }
                else{
                    alert('Ошибка Ajax: Данные не получены!');
                }
            }else{
                alert('Ошибка Ajax: '+ this.statusText);
            }
        }
    }
    request.send(body);
},
```

Вот php код

```
if(isset($_POST['user'])){

$data = json_decode($_POST['user'],true);
$decodedpass = md5(md5(trim($data['password'])));
$pass = substr($decodedpass, 0,13);
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_login, user_password FROM users WHERE user_login = '". $mysqli->real_escape_string($data['login'])."'");
$queryArray = $query->fetch_assoc();

if($data['login'] === $queryArray['user_login'] && $pass === $queryArray['user_password']){

    $user_hash = generateCode(10);
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET user_hash = '".$user_hash."' WHERE user_login='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($data['login'])."'");
    setcookie('user_hash', $user_hash, time() + 60*60*24*30);
    setcookie('user_name', $data['login'], time() + 60*60*24*30);
    header("Location: http://tasks/task_1/php/user_page.php"); # не работает
}else{
    echo 'Wrong data';
}
```

Если ввести неправильные данные код срабатывает, при правильном вводе возникает ошибка, точнее активация js кода( }else{
                alert('Ошибка Ajax: '+ this.statusText);). Можно перенаправить по средствам JavaScript конечно, но было бы интересно знать в чем причина такого поведения. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: *при правильном вводе возникает ошибка* -- приведите ошибку.

Comment: активируется участок кода js фала, а именно     }else{
                alert('Ошибка Ajax: '+ this.statusText);

Comment: чему равен `this.status` в вашем случае ?

Comment: jekaby, status равен нулю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подозреваю, ошибка у вас в логике есть.

Какой смысл отправлять редирект при ajax-запросе?
Вы на сервер отправили ajax методом POST. Который в свою очередь редиректит на какую то страницу методом GET!

Думаю, что именно по этому браузер и не даёт ajax выполняться. 
Не нужно делать location редирект, а отрендерите то, что должно выводитья в скрипте `user_page.php` и отдайте непосредственно html без редиректа.

Comment: Смысл был просто а эксперименте, проверял валидность данных на клиенте, а потом отправлял уже.  А по поводу редиректа heder("Location"), не знал что он использует метод GET. Спасибо!